# React - Can't Change prefilled input value from backend

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks

Working on React application and have encountered a little issue, where I am not able to clear my input value, after typing value was returned/prefilled from backend Tried googling this problem, found some similar threads here, but I was not able to resolve this.

***Requirements***: `name` atribute should be required also typed value should be printed outside input so i used `value` with `defaultValue`.

***Solutions with downsides***

1. Remove "name" atribute, but i will loose prefilled value
2. Remove `value`, `defaultValue`, and `onChange` handler but when i will loose value to be printed out.

***Example***
[image]
Can someone help with this issue what fills all conditions. Simplified my code to be more easy to understand my approach:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setPartnerSlug(event.target.value);
  // Also tried:
  // setValue({
  //   ...value,
  //   [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  // });
};

<input
  name="name"
  label="label"
  placeholder="placeholder"
  value={value}
  defaultValue={value}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
Print Value: {value} // Required: Display typed input value
```

Comment: The steps seem right Try this... `onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}`

Comment: don't work, still can't type

Comment: @zahrazamani yes, for the simple input is working but in this case the value is filled from backend on init. Also i'm using input from `ant desing`, i just simplified code example i think it's not depending on it